# Copy files with gulp while preserving modification time

Tags: gulp

**Situation:**

I currently have a little gulp task that prepares my project files to be deployed via FTP. It's nothing fancy, but this simple project doesn't need more, at this time.

The whole deploy task has a "sub task" which simply grabs a list of paths, and copies all files to a `__deploy` directory:

```
/*
    Path: Folder path for a prepared deploy
 */
var deployBasePath = '__deploy/';  


/*
    Paths: Include all paths into deploy and excluded unneeded files. 
 */    
var deployIncludePaths = [
    '**/*',
    '.htaccess',
    '!{__deploy,__deploy/**}',
    '!{.git,.git/**}',
    '!assets/{js-sources,js-sources/**}',
    '!assets/{scss,scss/**}',
    '!assets/{vendor,vendor/**}',
    '!{node_modules,node_modules/**}',
    '!{panel,panel/**}',
    '!thumbs/**',
    '!.bowerrc',
    '!.gitignore',
    '!.gitmodules',
    '!bower.json',
    '!composer.{json,lock}',
    '!gulpfile.js',
    '!package.json',
    '!readme.md'
];


gulp.task('deploy-copy', ['deploy-cleanup', 'css', 'js'], function() {
    return gulp.src(deployIncludePaths)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(deployBasePath));
});
```

This will copy the project files to a `__deploy` directory and exclude all the gulp, bower, composer config files as well as SCSS and JS sources. The `deploy-cleanup` task it's calling simply cleans out the deploy directory.

---

**Problem:**

There is a part of the projects code that uses file modification dates to create sitemaps, etc. Unfortunately, this behavior cannot be changed.

**Therefor it would be helpful, if there was a way to copy the files just like the above task does, however while preserving all files modification dates (or at least files from a specified directory).**

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this still a problem?  I dug around in the source code and there is definitely no option to enable this, however I didn't see any explicit place where it was updating the modified time.  I would assume that is a default behavior of some library.  Sounds like something similar to `gulp.dest()` will need to be created that ensures the modified time is not changed.

Comment: Yes, I'd still like to be able to copy files while preserving the modification timestamp.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I needed this too, but could not find anything suitable, I've written the [gulp-preservetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preservetime) plugin to do it.

Example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var preservetime = require('gulp-preservetime');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'))
        .pipe(preservetime());
});
```

Comment: This sounded ideal but it doesn't seem to work for me. Does it work for others?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gulp-newer` for that.

Here the example from it:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

var imgSrc = 'src/img/**';
var imgDest = 'build/img';

// Minify any new images 
gulp.task('images', function() {

  // Add the newer pipe to pass through newer images only 
  return gulp.src(imgSrc)
      .pipe(newer(imgDest))
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDest));

});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch(imgSrc, ['images']);
});
```